# Arrow functions as class properties using Babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, babeljs, ecmascript-next

Can someone explain how Babel in React supports fat arrow functions as class properties?
Using Babel [Try it out](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAECKCuBTCAXAlgewHbQN4Ch9poBbATwAUAnDAB2gF5oAKASkYD48jjorEU8KjgDkACUQgQGADTQA7hiogAJgEIRAbh4BfHj3IAxeFmBtuvPgKGiJU2QqWqN24nuL49QA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&lineWrap=false&presets=react&prettier=true&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=1.6.2) I can see they are not supported:

```
class Question {

  // Property (not supported)
  myProp = () => {
    return 'Hello, world!';
  }

  // Method (supported)
  myFunc() {
    return 'Hello, world!';
  }

}
```

Class properties are not supported in ES6 (correct me if I'm wrong) but then in React (with Babel) they work.

I can see the difference between methods and properties using TypeScript [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20Question%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20myProp%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20'Hello%2C%20world!'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20myFunc()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20'Hello%2C%20world!'%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A) but I can't clearly understand if Babel is supporting them or not.
Is there some plug-in?

UPDATE:
I can see they are supported using [`"babel-preset-stage-0"`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/).

Comment: on the left side if you click on `stage-0` it works.. Babel supports them.

Comment: Your question is if babel supports them, if i understood you correctly. Yes it does. That is why there is babel preset stage 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To support class properties, you need to install and add [`babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/) to the `plugins` setting of your `.babelrc` (or in your `webpack` config).

Note that this plugin is also included in

- [`babel-preset-stage-0`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/)
- [`babel-preset-stage-1`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-1)
- [`babel-preset-stage-2`](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2)

So if you use one of those, you don't need to install `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties` by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

As @illiteratewriter suggested class properties are supported from [Stage 0 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-0/). For the time being, they are supported until [Stage 2 preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-2/):

> The proposal must now additionally have a formal description of the syntax and semantics of the feature (using the formal language of the ECMAScript specification). The description should be as complete as possible, but can contain todos and placeholders. Two experimental implementations of the feature are needed, but one of them can be in a transpiler such as Babel.

Comment: They are still in stage 2 (https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields).

Comment: @GG. Sorry, I messed up with the transpiler. I've updated my answer, thank you.