# Can't define arrow methods in react components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I am trying to convert all methods of my react components to arrow functions so that I don't have to bind them before hand. but whenever I shift a method to that syntax the react starts giving error. However, the the anonymous arrow functions work alright. E.g. onClick={(e)=>{e.preventDefault()}} works fine.

I am not sure but I think it might be a problem with vrsion of react or eslintrc configurations.

Here is my code:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    handleChangeStart = startDate => {
        //this method is giving error for not being defined
    }

    handleChangeEnd(endDate) {
        //method that doesn't gives error.
    }
    render(){
        <DatePicker
             id='start_dt'
             className="border border-primary text-center"
             selected={this.props.startDate}
             selectsStart
             startDate={this.props.startDate}
             endDate={this.props.endDate}
             onChange={this.handleChangeStart}
             dateFormatCalendar={"MMM YYYY"}
             dropdownMode={"select"}
         />
        <DatePicker
             id='start_dt'
             className="border border-primary text-center"
             selected={this.props.startEnd}
             selectsEnd
             startDate={this.props.startDate}
             endDate={this.props.endDate}
             onChange={this.handleChangeEnd}
             dateFormatCalendar={"MMM YYYY"}
             dropdownMode={"select"}
         />
    }
}
```

Here is my eslintrc file:

```
{
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true,
    "modules": true
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint"
}
```

Failed to compile.

./src/components/stats/Statistics.jsx
  Line 132:  'handleChangeStart' is not defined  no-undef

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Edit:

I changed my `react-script` dependency version from `1.0.7` to `3.0.1` in my `package.json` file and the error is gone. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: can you please post your babel config?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow functions as class properties using Babel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350702/arrow-functions-as-class-properties-using-babel)

Comment: I think you need to configure your webpack / babel to compile ES6 arrow functions.

Comment: Add the `@babel/preset-env` to you `webpack.config.js` `presets` array.

Comment: @Nick Zuber, how to do that.

Comment: @Amit Das, I don't have a 'webpack.config.js' file.

Comment: You using create-react-app?

Comment: @MatteoBasso I don't have a babel config in project.

Comment: @AmitDas no, I on boarded my current project just now this project was written by my predecessors. And I can't tell if they used create-react-app or not.

Answer (score 2):

You're setting the class field `handleChangeStart` (currently not everywhere supported), which will not define a prototype function on the `MyComponent` class. If you'd like to use arrow functions you can do so in multiple ways, the easiest being:

1. Using the constructor.

   ```
   class MyComponent extends React.Component {
     constructor(...args) {
       // pass forward any arguments to the react component constructor
       super(...args);

       // keep in mind that this doesn't set the prototype, but a property
       this.handleChangeStart = startDate => {
         // ...
       };
     }

     // ...
   }
   ```
2. Using `prototype`.

   ```
   class MyComponent extends React.Component {
     // ...
   }

   MyComponent.prototype.handleChangeStart = startDate => {
     // ...
   };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? I am new to react but this worked for me

```
const handleChangeStart = (startDate) => {

    }
```

Comment: Specifying `var/let/const` will not work with `classFeilds`. Read more about [TC39](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields). Also `()` around a single parametered arrow functions is not needed.

Comment: @AmitDas Ahh Did not know that. Ty

Answer (score 0):

I don't see your implementation of the arrow functions that would give an error. I assume you use *this* keyword in your functions. Javascript arrow function doesn't capture caller in *this* keyboard, while the regular function declared with *function* keyword would have an this as the caller.

Whenever you call this in your arrow function it will represent the *this* in the outer scope, sometimes this is what you want, but most times this will give you some kind of error.

Comment: Try limiting the answer options to `solutions` only. Your answer should rather be a comment.