# Got map of undefined when tried to pass array into children component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and was working with Open Weather Map to create weather app. What I wanted to achieve is to pass array of days to children component and then use map function to render the days in the array in children component. Here is the code I am using:

```
import React, { Fragment, Component } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import SearchBox from "./Containers/SearchBox/SearchBox";
import Header from "./Components/Header/Header";
import styles from "./App.module.css";
import CardContainer from "./Containers/CardContainer/CardContainer";
import axios from "axios";
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    title: []
  };

  getTitle(title) {
    axios
      .get(
        `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${title}&APPID=7ad09d078633b652ecef8587a337639e&units=metric`
      )
      .then(res => { //Here I am retrieving data from JSON file received from server
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          title: [...prevState.title, res.data.city.name] //Here I want to access data about name of city
        }));
        this.setState(prevState => ({
          title: [...prevState.title, res.data.list] //This is list array containing days with certain forecast
        }));
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Fragment>
          <Header title={"Weather App"} />
          <div className="container">
            <SearchBox getRequest={this.getTitle.bind(this)} />
          </div>
          <h1 className={styles.cityWeather}>{this.state.title[0]}</h1>
          <CardContainer weatherData={this.state.title[1]} /> //Here I am passing that array of days into child component
        </Fragment>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

import React from "react";
import CardItem from "./CardItem/CardItem";

const CardContainer = ({ weatherData }) => {
  return (
    <main>
      {weatherData.map(day => { //HERE I AM GETTING ERROR
        return <p>{day}</p>;
      })}
    </main>
  );
};

export default CardContainer;
```

[image]

Comment: Use arrow function for getTitle() method getTitle = title => {} then you do not have to bind this

Comment: Your `weatherData` maybe `undefined`. Try `Array.isArray(weatherData) && weatherData.map(...)`

Comment: weatherData={this.state.title[1]} there are you passing one title only or array of titles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.state.title[1]`, `this.state.title[0]` are `undefined` till you make the `GET` request.

You should add a condition before trying to `map` undefined value or add `state` initial value:

```
const CardContainer = ({ weatherData }) => (
  <main>{weatherData && weatherData.map(day => <p>{day}</p>)}</main>
);

// Or adding an initial value
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    title: ['initial1', 'initial2']
  };
  ....
}
```

Also note that by using [babel's arrow functions as class properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49350702/arrow-functions-as-class-properties-using-babel) (enabled by default), you can avoid binding every function to `this` (which is error-prone).

```
// Avoid <SearchBox getRequest={this.getTitle.bind(this)} />
// Using class arrow function:

class App extends Component {
  getTitle = title => {
     ....
  };

  // use this.getTitle(...) without binding
}
```

Comment: hey Dennis thank you for your kind answer, please change weather to weatherData in the first code block. Also, I read that getTitle = title => {
     ....
  }; is also not best practice. Should I use only constructor to bind handlers? Or it is ok to use what you suggested

Comment: On the contrary - using constructor is a bad practice (forgetting `super`,`bind`, not using a life cycle, forgetting `props` in super and much more), avoid it. Try using arrow function and class properties (like you used `state`)